# Apex Class Array to JSON - Blank data is being sent

Tags: apex, json, httprequest

The requirement is to send an array (Item text to JSON from APEX Class).
The issue is APEX Class is passing empty array to JSON. ("ItemText":[] )

JSON code below

```
  <ns0:QUOTATION_TEXT>
{%- for item in content.QuoteLineItem %}{% assign itemNo = forloop.index | Times: 10 | Plus: 1000000 | Date: "" | Slice: 1, 6 -%}
{%- for subItem in item.ItemText -%}
<ns1:BAPISDTEXT xmlns:ns1="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Rfc/">
  {%- if content.QuoteHeader.SalesDocNo != "" and content.QuoteHeader.SalesDocNo != null -%}
  <ns1:DOC_NUMBER>{{content.QuoteHeader.SalesDocNo}}</ns1:DOC_NUMBER>
  {%- endif -%}
  <ns1:ITM_NUMBER>{{ itemNo }}</ns1:ITM_NUMBER>
  <ns1:TEXT_ID>{{ subItem.TextId }}</ns1:TEXT_ID>
  <ns1:LANGU>{{ subItem.LanguageKey }}</ns1:LANGU>
  <ns1:LANGU_ISO>{{ subItem.LanguageISOKey }}</ns1:LANGU_ISO>
  <ns1:TEXT_LINE>{{ subItem.TextBody }}</ns1:TEXT_LINE>
</ns1:BAPISDTEXT>
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

For the above code, I modified the APEX class as below.

```
public class PayLoad_QuoteLineItem {
    public String Material { get; set; }
    public String RejectReason { get; set; }
    public Date BillingDate { get; set; }
    public String Plant { get; set; }
    public Integer TargetQty { get; set; }
    public String TargetQtyUoM { get; set; }
    public String ItemCategory { get; set; }
    public String PowerRecoverable { get; set; }
    public String IndexationRateCode { get; set; }
    public String ServiceClass { get; set; }
    public String ItemReference { get; set; }
    public String SalesDistrict { get; set; }
    public Date PriceDate { get; set; }
    public String Division { get; set; }
    public String ProfitCentre { get; set; }
    public String CustomerPO { get; set; }
    public Date CustomerPODate { get; set; }
    public String IndexationMonth { get; set; }
    public String AccountAssignment { get; set; }
    public PayLoad_PartnerRole ItemPartnerRole { get; set; }
    public PayLoad_MaintainingConditions ItemMaintainingConditions { get; set; }
    public PayLoad_ContractData ItemContractData { get; set; }
    public PayLoad_CustomFields ItemCustomFields { get; set; }
    public PayLoad_Text [] ItemText  { get; set; }

}

    public class PayLoad_Text {
    public String TextId { get; set; }
    public String LanguageKey { get; set; }
    public String LanguageISOKey { get; set; }
    public String TextBody { get; set; }
} 

qli.ItemText  = new PayLoad_Text[]{}; 

            PayLoad_Text t1 = new PayLoad_Text();
            t1.TextId = '0001';
            t1.LanguageKey = 'E';
            t1.LanguageISOKey = 'EN';
            t1.TextBody = quote.Comments_to_appear_on_Invoice__c;

            PayLoad_Text t2 = new PayLoad_Text();
            t2.TextId = 'Z002';
            t2.LanguageKey = 'E';
            t2.LanguageISOKey = 'EN';
            t2.TextBody = quote.Customer_Site_Reference__c;

            PayLoad_Text t3 = new PayLoad_Text();
            t3.TextId = 'Z003';
            t3.LanguageKey = 'E';
            t3.LanguageISOKey = 'EN';
            t3.TextBody = quote.link_to_supporting_documents__c;
```

Not sure if I have to change the above array logic in APEX CLASS.
Note : Only code snippets that are related to Itemtext logic is given. I need help in adding Array logic in APEX Class so that I can send 3 sets of values to JSON

Comment: What's the actual problem?  Are you getting an error?  Please take the time to clearly articulate what you're asking for help.

Comment: The issue is APEX Class is passing empty array to JSON. ("ItemText":[] )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never adding `t1`, `t2`, `t3` to your list

After declaring each `Payload_Text` you need to add it to the array.

e.g.

```
qli.ItemText.add(t1);
qli.ItemText.add(t2);
qli.ItemText.add(t3);
```